# How to visualize original builtin.py file

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, built-in, pylance

I was curious about how are made some built-in functions of Python (like `print()`, `input()`, etc.) but when I select "Go to Definition" or "Go to Declaration" VSCode takes me to some Stub_files.pyi that don't make me able to visualize the code of the functions but only the params of the function.

PS: I think those buttons "Go to..." are made by the extension Pylance.

How can I make that VSCode takes me to the original builtin.py file?

Comment: Not sure about Vscode, which certainly has integration issues, which cannot take to the metadata, but on REPL, you can use dir(method / library) to know all functions, then call some of those functions to know more details

Comment: ah ok, I will look there. Thank you, man :)

Comment: Edit: I looked and it shows me only the methods related to the function I put in `dir` but I wanna see how do they works, the code in the function that makes it work.
Example: print() -> `for arg in args: __print(arg)`

Comment: those functions are written in C and made available like all C-wrapper libraries do.

Comment: and can I visualize them in vscode? are there in a specific folder?